# Looking to improve query performance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, performance, optimization, query-performance

This is my query:

```
select S-Num.Title, 
       jobs.JobNum, 
       jobs.JobPart, 
       Part.PartNum, 
       jobs.RevisionNum,
       jobs.Seq,
       jobs.Parent, 
       Part.PartDescription, 
       jobs.part_type 
from S-Num
inner join 
(
    select Asem.jobNum as JobNum, 
           Asem.job_part as JobPart, 
           Asem.Asem as Part, 
           Asem.RevisionNum, 
           Asem.AssemblySeq as Seq, 
           Asem.Parent, 
           Asem.part_type
    from Asem 

    union   

    select Mats.jobNum as JobNum, 
           Mats.job_part as JobPart, 
           Mats.material as Part, 
           Mats.RevisionNum, 
           Mats.MtlSeq as Seq, 
           Mats.Parent, 
           Mats.part_type
    from Mats
) as jobs on S-Num.JobNum = jobs.JobNum
inner join Part on Part.PartNum = jobs.Part
where S-Num.Title = 'user selected data'
order by jobs.part_type, jobs.Seq, jobs.Parent ;
```

As you can see there are 4 tables here:

1. `S-Num` 230k Records - this table has the only thing the end user knows
   which happens to be the title. Upon looking up the title we get the
   `JobNumber` which is what ties the  table to `Asem` and
   `Mats`.
2. `Asem` 2m Records - contains many records for each
   JobNumber. one record for each associated part of the assembly. so
   it has the key to join off of the `Part` table.
3. `Mats` 20m Records - contains many records for each `JobNumber`. one
   record for each associated part of the materials. So it has the key
   to join off of the `Part` table.
4. `Part` 25k Records - contains just the part number and desc which is needed for resulting table. gathered for each assembly and material.

There are no primary keys so building foreign keys is not possible. I have built a clustered index on the `Asem` (2m Records) and `Mats` (20m Records) tables for `JobNum` column. However, results still take between 3 and 5 seconds. This is mainly because of the `Mats` and its 20 million records as if I take it out of the query it takes about a second. This data is from a client so we cannot alter it to include a lookup table which could manage the 1 to many relationship and handle the relationship better. It would become a maintenance nightmare as this data is also not stagnate.

The results is just a table with the columns I have listed for the end user to see what is made up of what.

I am not a DBA, nor do we have one in house. I am just a programmer attempting to get the best performance out of this situation.

Thanks for the help!

--edit-- all this on Ms SQL Server 2008R2

--edit2-- off of the orig query I came up with I am getting a 10% cost with the Clustered index scan against the Asem table and I am getting 84% cost against the Clustered Indec Scan for the Mats table.

Comment: Is it possible to replace `union` with `union all`?

Comment: No primary keys?! What about unique keys?

Comment: I agree with Colin, a union all should help. With a union, all the rows from Asem2mrecords are being compared with all the rows from Mats20mRecords looking for duplicates.

Comment: @ypercube - These are not the table names - I changed them so that you can see the scope of the tables better.

Comment: @Colin 't Hart - I have had similar results with union vs union all - just tried it again and both are taking 4 seconds to complete. and there is nothing unique about the tables - again not mine I just have to deal with it.

Comment: Is the list of columns you are selecting from Mats20mRecords and Asem2mRecords all the columns in the table. if not you could potentially gain some performance by creating a non-clustered index on jobnum and including the other columns. there may be less pages to read. if you just run the select on Mats20mRecords, how long does that take?

Comment: Is there an index on `S-Num (title, jobnum)` or on `S-Num (title)` ?

Comment: @BobKlimes It is all of the columns. And if I run a query against the Mats20mRecords just looking up the jobNum from the S-Num table it takes 0 seconds. Which makes me think that there is something I can be doing better in my query.

Comment: @ypercube there is not

Comment: Please add the actual execution plan from your query to the question.

Comment: And the tables definitions. You refer to clustered index scan and people who want to answer have no idea what the clustered indexes are (or if some tables have no indexes at all).

Answer (score 0):

you could try to split the two queries in the union to join all other tables and then union those results.

I created the tables with the clustered indexes and updated statistics to mimic the row counts specified.

```
    CREATE TABLE [Part25kRecords]([PartNum] int,
                              [PartDescription] varchar(10));
CREATE TABLE [Mats20mRecords]([jobNum] int,
                              [job_part] int ,
                              [material] int,
                              [RevisionNum] int,
                              [mtlSeq] varchar(10),
                              [Parent] int,
                              [part_type] int);
CREATE TABLE [S-Num230kRecords]([title] varchar(10),
                                [JobNum] int);
CREATE TABLE [Asem2mRecords]([jobNum] int,
                             [job_part] int ,
                             [assembly] int,
                             [RevisionNum] int,
                             [AssemblySeq] varchar(10),
                             [Parent] int,
                             [part_type] int);

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [CL_Asem2mRecords] ON [Asem2mRecords]([JobNum]);
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [CL_Mats20mRecords] ON [Mats20mRecords]([JobNum]);

UPDATE STATISTICS [Asem2mRecords] WITH ROWCOUNT = 2000000;
UPDATE STATISTICS [Mats20mRecords] WITH ROWCOUNT = 20000000;
UPDATE STATISTICS [S-Num230kRecords] WITH ROWCOUNT = 230000;
UPDATE STATISTICS [Part25kRecords] WITH ROWCOUNT = 25000;
```

then when running the query above and a rewritten query moving the union, I get a much better execution plan with the new query.

```
SELECT [S-Num230kRecords].[Title],
       [jobs].[JobNum],
       [jobs].[JobPart],
       [Part25kRecords].[PartNum],
       [jobs].[RevisionNum],
       [jobs].[Seq],
       [jobs].[Parent],
       [Part25kRecords].[PartDescription],
       [jobs].[part_type]
FROM [S-Num230kRecords]
     INNER JOIN(
                SELECT [Asem2mRecords].[jobNum] AS      [JobNum],
                       [Asem2mRecords].[job_part] AS    [JobPart],
                       [Asem2mRecords].[assembly] AS    [Part],
                       [Asem2mRecords].[RevisionNum],
                       [Asem2mRecords].[AssemblySeq] AS [Seq],
                       [Asem2mRecords].[Parent],
                       [Asem2mRecords].[part_type]
                FROM [Asem2mRecords]
                UNION ALL
                SELECT [Mats20mRecords].[jobNum] AS   [JobNum],
                       [Mats20mRecords].[job_part] AS [JobPart],
                       [Mats20mRecords].[material] AS [Part],
                       [Mats20mRecords].[RevisionNum],
                       [Mats20mRecords].[MtlSeq] AS   [Seq],
                       [Mats20mRecords].[Parent],
                       [Mats20mRecords].[part_type]
                FROM [Mats20mRecords])AS [jobs]
     ON [S-Num230kRecords].[JobNum] = [jobs].[JobNum]
     INNER JOIN [Part25kRecords]
     ON [Part25kRecords].[PartNum] = [jobs].[Part]
WHERE [S-Num230kRecords].[Title] = 'user selected data'
ORDER BY [jobs].[part_type], [jobs].[Seq], [jobs].[Parent];

SELECT [S-Num230kRecords].[Title],
       [jobs].[JobNum],
       [jobs].[Job_Part],
       [Part25kRecords].[PartNum],
       [jobs].[RevisionNum],
       [jobs].[AssemblySeq],
       [jobs].[Parent],
       [Part25kRecords].[PartDescription],
       [jobs].[part_type]
FROM [S-Num230kRecords]
     INNER JOIN [Asem2mRecords] AS [jobs]
     ON [S-Num230kRecords].[JobNum] = [jobs].[JobNum]
     INNER JOIN [Part25kRecords]
     ON [Part25kRecords].[PartNum] = [jobs].[assembly]
WHERE [S-Num230kRecords].[Title] = 'user selected data'
UNION ALL
SELECT [S-Num230kRecords].[Title],
       [jobs].[JobNum],
       [jobs].[Job_Part],
       [Part25kRecords].[PartNum],
       [jobs].[RevisionNum],
       [jobs].[mtlSeq],
       [jobs].[Parent],
       [Part25kRecords].[PartDescription],
       [jobs].[part_type]
FROM [S-Num230kRecords]
     INNER JOIN [Mats20mRecords] AS [jobs]
     ON [S-Num230kRecords].[JobNum] = [jobs].[JobNum]
     INNER JOIN [Part25kRecords]
     ON [Part25kRecords].[PartNum] = [jobs].[material]
WHERE [S-Num230kRecords].[Title] = 'user selected data';
```

These results dont take into account data distribution and it could be better with indexes on part25krecords and S-num230krecords
[image: Original query]

[image: Rewritten query]

Comment: I tried your query and it is taking twice as long in the actual environment unfortunately. On the Hash Match for Mats20mRecords it costs me 31% and the Clustered Index Scan costs me 56%. I also tried to pull out the inner join on the part number out of the two queries and wrapped it outside with the same results just as a stab in the dark. execution plan is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the queries to execute in under a second by running two separate queries with only joining the mat or assem tables with the parts table and looking up via the jobNumber which is available from the title lookup.

I also tried making a view and a stored proc in order to test performance with the originally query but to no avail. queries took just as long.

Answer (score -3):

I'd look at changing the union to union all to remove the overhead of making the data in the subquery distinct. Then use group by to remove the duplicates

Comment: done and query takes the same amount of time.